# Remove key-value pairs found in subsequent rows while looping 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering, key-value

I have a two dimensional array with indexed rows of associative elements.  I need to retain the first occurring key-value pairs while iterating from the start of the array to the end.

Input:

```
$ar = [
     ["a" => "b", "c" => "d", "h" => "e"],
     ["a" = "b", "f" => "g"]
];
```

I've tried `array_unique()`, but it's not suitable for thistask.

Expected result:

```
[
     ["a" => "b", "c" => "d", "h" => "e"],
     ["f" => "g"]
]
```

---

Another example:

```
$ar = [
    ["a" => "b", "b" => "w", "c" => "e"!],
    ["c" => "g", "a" => "b"]
];
```

Expected result:

```
[
    ["a" => "b", "b" => "w", "c" => "e"],
    ["c" => "g"]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In this scenario, you need to be careful with duplicate keys yet different values. So match to remove duplicates has to be on combination of both key and value.
- To do this, we can collect all keys in an array say `$map` and have all values visited for this keys inside that key array.
- Now, we can just do an `in_array` check to get hold of whether we got some key-value pair like this before or not.

**Snippet:**

```
$arr = [
    [
        'a' => 'b',
        'c' => 'd',
        'h' => 'e'
    ],
    [
        'a' => 'b',
        'f' => 'g',
        'c' => 'f'
    ],
    [
        'a' => 'd',
        'c' => 'd'
    ]
];

$map = [];
foreach($arr as $index => $data){
    foreach($data as $key => $value){
        if(!isset($map[$key])) $map[$key] = [];
        if(in_array($value,$map[$key])) unset($arr[$index][$key]);
        else $map[$key][] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($arr);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/RWcMu

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [array_diff()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) and [unset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) functions. But, you need to decode this JSON values firstly:

```
foreach($ar as $in => &$js){
    $ar[$in] = json_decode($js,true);
}
```

After this `$ar` has a view like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => b
            [c] => d
            [h] => e
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => b
            [f] => g
        )

)
```

Here you can apply `array_diff()` function:

```
$diff = array_diff($ar[1],array_diff($ar[1],$ar[0]));
```

It will collect duplicates from `[1]` index in `[0]`:

```
Array
(
    [a] => b
)
```

Now you can `unset` these values from `[1]` index:

```
foreach($diff as $ind=>$uns){
    unset($ar[1][$ind]);
}
```

And finally you can change JSON view back:

```
foreach($ar as $in=>&$js){
    $ar[$in] = json_encode($js);
}
```

Result would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => {"a":"b","c":"d","h":"e"}
    [1] => {"f":"g"}
)
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/niWVp)**

If input elements are objects, then use this loop at the first step:

```
foreach($ar as $in=>&$obj){
    $ar[$in] = (array)$obj;  
}
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/F9bM6)**

Comment: $ar = Array (
     0 =>'{"a":"b", "a":"w", "a":"e"}',
     1 =>'{"a":"b", "a":"g"}'
);

In this scenario, that is doesn't work.

Comment: @Aksen I have transferred the commented input into the question (kind of) and removed the unnecessary json component from the task (because it is not likely to represent other developers' scenarios). Your answer was not making associative comparisons, so you may wish to update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend:

- not iterating the first row (because its values will always be preserved) then
- iterating the remaining rows then
- making associative comparisons between the current row and all previous rows.

This filters the input array, row-by-row, and therefore improves performance by reducing the number of comparisons executed on each subsequent row.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GkqY8))

```
for ($i = 1, $count = count($array); $i < $count; ++$i) {
    $array[$i] = array_diff_assoc(
        $array[$i],
        ...array_slice($array, 0, $i, true)
    );
}
var_export($array);
```

Input:

```
$array = [
    [
        'a' => 'b',
        'c' => 'd',
        'h' => 'e',
        'i' => 'm'
    ],
    [
        'a' => 'b',
        'f' => 'g',
        'c' => 'f'
    ],
    [
        'a' => 'd',
        'c' => 'd'
    ],
    [
        'i' => 'm'
    ]
];
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'a' => 'b',
    'c' => 'd',
    'h' => 'e',
    'i' => 'm',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'f' => 'g',
    'c' => 'f',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'a' => 'd',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
  ),
)
```