# Remove subsets from each row where the same subset is found in another row

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates, filtering

I need to remove objects from a 3d array where the same two-property object is found in any other row.

I previously asked [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59838726/2943403), but my new requirements are slightly different because I was keeping one of the encountered duplicates. Now I would like for both/all encountered duplicates to be removed.

```
[
    [
        ["name" => "John", "surname" => "Smith"],
        ["name" => "Kate", "surname" => "Winston"]
    ],
    [
        ["name" => "Kate", "surname" => "Winston"],
        ["name" => "Jack", "surname" => "Irving"]
    ],
]
```

Desired filtered result with same original structure:

```
[
    [
        ["name" => "John", "surname" => "Smith"],
    ],
    [
        ["name" => "Jack", "surname" => "Irving"]
    ],
]
```

Comment: You should accept the answer which best answered your previous question. That said, your JSON values in each element is not a valid JSON -- so my question is, how does the values of that array get generated?

Comment: @vivek_23 it's closed.

Comment: @Mlacek I hope that actually solved your previous problem.

Comment: @Qirel I get the values from query, and trim [].

Comment: Show `var_dump()` of those array. Too many ways possible to apply as a solution and each one depends on input data type.

Comment: Example. [0]=>string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like others answers don't see their own final results and don't read desired output.

Here a little bit hard solution but it works well.

*Note: the input data array must have 2 object indexes and 2 arrays of objects for comparing, otherwise, it should be fixed.*

```
$ar =  Array (
  0 => [(object)["name"=>"John", "surname"=>"Smith"], (object)["name"=>"Kate", "surname"=>"Winston"]],
  1 => [(object)["name"=>"Kate", "surname"=>"Winston"], (object)["name"=>"Jack", "surname"=>"Irving"]] 
);
```

```
$arr = []; 
$k = 0;         // do `if statement` only once
foreach($ar as $num=>&$subar){ 
    foreach($subar as $num2=>$pers){
        $subar[$num2] = (array)$pers;          // object to array

        if (!$k) {
            $keys = array_keys($subar[$num2]); // collect "name" and "surname" in an array
            $k++;
        }

        foreach($subar[$num2] as $a=>$b){
            $seq = array_search($a,$keys);      // index of the current key 

            if (!$seq) {                        // 0 -> "name", 1 -> "surname"
                $arr[$num][$b] = '';
            } else { 
                $arr[$num][$subar[$num2][current($keys)]] = $b;
            } 
        }
    } 
} 

 $diff[] = array_diff($arr[0],$arr[1]);     // clear duplicates from 1-st set
 $diff[] = array_diff($arr[1],$arr[0]);     // clear duplicates from 2-nd set
```

Gives result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [John] => Smith
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Jack] => Irving
        )

)
```

And after you can re-create the output array:

```
// creating a new array
$res = [];
foreach($diff as $num=>$ns){
    foreach($ns as $name=>$surname){
        foreach($keys as $ind=>$key){
            if ($ind % 2 == 0){
                $tmp[$key] = $name;     // put name
            } else { 
                $tmp[$key] = $surname;  // put surname
            }
        }  
        $res[$num] = (object)$tmp;      // array to object
    }
 }
```

Output will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => John
            [surname] => Smith
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Jack
            [surname] => Irving
        )

)
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/nqCjo)**

In case of string values in the input arrays, i.e.:

```
$ar = [
    '[{"name":"John", "surname":"Smith"}, {"name":"Kate", "surname":"Winston"}]',
    '[{"name":"Kate", "surname":"Winston"}, {"name":"Jack", "surname":"Irving"}]'
];
```

You need a little fix:

```
...
foreach($ar as $num=>&$subar){ 
    $ar[$num] = json_decode($subar);

    foreach($subar as $num2=>$pers){
...
```

The same output you will get.

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/aDB8F)**

Answer (score 0):

It's easier if you *don't* trim away the brackets `[]`, as you stated that you did in the comments. That way, they are proper JSON strings, which we can use in PHP.

Map (or loop) over your array, and build up a `$result` array, where you append all the arrays from your decoded JSON. Once you have your final `$result`, you have an array that looks somewhat like

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => John
            [surname] => Smith
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Kate
            [surname] => Winston
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Kate
            [surname] => Winston
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Jack
            [surname] => Irving
        )
)
```

We have all the values in an actual array now, but there are duplicates -- which can be removed using `array_unique()` with the `SORT_REGULAR` flag.

```
$array = [
    '[{"name":"John", "surname":"Smith"}, {"name":"Kate", "surname":"Winston"}]',
    '[{"name":"Kate", "surname":"Winston"}, {"name":"Jack", "surname":"Irving"}]'
];

$result = [];
array_map(function($v) use (&$result) {
    $result = array_merge($result, json_decode($v, true));
}, $array);

print_r(array_unique($result, SORT_REGULAR));
```

Final output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => John
            [surname] => Smith
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Kate
            [surname] => Winston
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Jack
            [surname] => Irving
        )

)
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/q6pZc

Comment: `Kate Winston`  should not be there in the output.

Comment: If I don't trim brackets, I get this: [0] => [{"name":"John", "surname":"Smith"}, {"name":"Kate", "surname":"Winston"}]

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = [
    '[{"name":"John", "surname":"Smith"}, {"name":"Kate", "surname":"Winston"}]',
    '[{"name":"Kate", "surname":"Winston"}, {"name":"Jack", "surname":"Irving"}]'
];
$resultArray = [];

foreach ($array as $item) {
    $bufferArray = array_merge($resultArray, json_decode($item));
    foreach ($bufferArray as $elements) {
        $key = $elements->name . $elements->surname;
        if (array_key_exists($key, $resultArray)) {
            unset($resultArray[$key]);
        } else {
            $resultArray[$key] = $elements;
        }
    }
}

print_r($resultArray);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [KateWinston] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Kate
            [surname] => Winston
        )

    [JackIrving] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Jack
            [surname] => Irving
        )

)
```

can rewrite this into more serious code )

Comment: What if someone has `Kat` and `eWinston` as their full name?

Answer (score 0):

To remove objects from each row where a given object exists any where in any other row, you can make iterates calls of `array_udiff()`.  Inside the function, the first parameter should be the currently iterated row and the next/subsequent parameter(s) should all of the other rows in the entire array.  The last parameter is the callback which compares whole objects to whole objects via PHP's performance-optimized algorithm.

My snippet below will not only handle your 2-row array, it will also handle arrays with 3 or more rows.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/p4ffv))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $i => $objs) {
    $cache = $array[$i];
    unset($array[$i]);
    $params = [
        $objs,
        ...$array,
        fn($a, $b) => $a <=> $b
    ];
    $result[] = array_udiff(...$params);
    $array[$i] = $cache;
}
var_export($result);
```

To be clear, [this snippet will work the same if the array of arrays of objects is an array of arrays of arrays](https://3v4l.org/YuDdl).